# Unity auto rotation of screen objects based on devices orientation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screen-orientation

I'm wanting to have singular objects within my game in Unity rotate based on the screen orientation of the screen. I've been playing about with Unity's in built [Screen Orientation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation.html) code but this moves the entire screen when I want only a single object in my screen to move.

Has anyone every achieved similar functionality without the need to create dedicated plug ins for either iOS or Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScreenOrientation is based for the screen only.
Most of the SmartPhone  have a gyroscope, and Unity can use it.

[Doc Unity : Gyroscope Rotation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Gyroscope-rotationRate.html)

You can then use rotation of the gyroscope.

Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [accelerometer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-acceleration.html) readings of the device. `Input.acceleration` provides value of acceleration between 0 to 1 in all Axis i.e X,Y and Z. you can use it . I have used it in my application and it worked great.